# Iterar sobre una lista y un diccionario para encontrar mutaciones en una secuencia de ADN

Tags: python, python-2.7

Quiero encontrar una serie de mutaciones al comparar un par de secuencias. Las mutaciones están definidas en dos diccionarios y las dos secuencias las he convertido en una lista de tuplas por posición con `zip()`.

He escrito el siguiente código, pero devuelve un valor muy superior a la longitud de las secuencias:

```
transicion = {'A':'G', 'G':'A', 'T':'C', 'C':'T'}

transversion = {'A':('T','C'), 'G':('T','C'), 'T':('A','G'), 'C':('A','G')}

def rel_trans(s1,s2):

    trans_result = 0

    for x in len(s1):

        for i,j in zip(s1, s2):

            for (i,j),(i1,j1) in zip(transicion.items(), transversion.items()):
            trans_result += 1

    return trans_result

s1 = 'CAACGCA'

s2 = 'TGTCTGA'

print rel_trans(s1,s2) # maximo deberia salir 7 y sale un valor mucho mayor
```

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que en ningún momento estas comparando una base con otra para ver si hay o no una mutación. Deberias hacer algo como:

```
transicion = {'A':'G', 'G':'A', 'T':'C', 'C':'T'}
transversion = {'A':('T','C'), 'G':('T','C'), 'T':('A','G'), 'C':('A','G')}

def rel_trans(s1,s2):
    res = 0
    for i,j in zip(s1, s2):
        if transicion[i] == j or j in transversion[i]:
            res += 1
    return (res)
```

O usando compresión de generadores:

```
def rel_trans(s1,s2):
    return sum(transicion[i] == j or j in transversion[i] for i,j in zip(s1, s2))

s1 = 'CAACGCA'
s2 = 'TGTCTGA'
print(rel_trans(s1,s2))
```

**Salida:**

> 5

Esto realmente tiene poco sentido si no obtienes las transversiones y transiciones por separado. De la forma anterior obtienes todas las mutaciones por sustitución posibles y para eso no necesitas los diccionarios (a no ser que buscaras solo algunas en específico y no las 12 posibles) ya que para eso basta con hacer (si son cadenas válidas que solo contienen los carácteres A, G, T, C):

```
def rel_trans(s1,s2):
    return sum(i==j for i, j in zip(s1, s2))
```

Algo más informativo sería:

```
transicion = {'A':'G', 'G':'A', 'T':'C', 'C':'T'}
transversion = {'A':('T','C'), 'G':('T','C'), 'T':('A','G'), 'C':('A','G')}

def  mutaciones_por_sustitucion(s1, s2):
    ts = [(ind+1, i, j) for ind, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)) if transicion[i] == j]
    tv = [(ind+1, i, j) for ind, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)) if j in transversion[i]]

    print('Encontradas {} mutaciones por sustitucion:'. format(len(ts)+len(tv)))
    print('    Transiciones ({}): '.format(len(ts)))
    for m in ts:
        print('        Posicion {}: {} cambiada por {}'.format(m[0], m[1], m[2]))

    print('    Transversiones ({}): '.format(len(tv)))
    for m in tv:
        print('        Posicion {}: {} cambiada por {}'.format(m[0], m[1], m[2]))


s1 = 'CAACGCA'
s2 = 'TGTCTGA'
mutaciones_por_sustitucion(s1, s2)
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> Encontradas 5 mutaciones por sustitucion:
>     Transiciones (2): 
>         Posicion 1: C cambiada por T
>         Posicion 2: A cambiada por G
>     Transversiones (3): 
>         Posicion 3: A cambiada por T
>         Posicion 5: G cambiada por T
>         Posicion 6: C cambiada por G
> ```